# Finding and appending an index of an array to the actual element inside the array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am having an array of objects. Each object has a property called a number.

```
 struct Age {
  var position = 0 
  }
```

I also have an array of those objects:

```
let age = Age()
let array = [age]
```

How can I append to the position property the index of the element in the array.

Something like:

```
for i in array {
i.position = i.index
}
```

Basically, the first item of the array which is at position 0 should make the i=0 second to 1,etc.

Comment: `array.indices.forEach { array[$0].position = $0 }`

Comment: Note that if you append, insert or replaceSubrange it will invalidade your position property as an index. I dont recommend saving the index of the element as a property of your structure element

Comment: Hi thank you very much. So how do you advice me to do it? I need to save the index of the element as a property because I am sorting the elements in an list and I need to re-arrange them every time when an item is deleted or appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` must be `var` and not `let` in order to be mutable and make this work:

```
var array = Array(repeating: Age(), count: 10) //build a sample array to test with
for index in 0..<array.count {
  array[index].position = index
}
print(array)
```

Which yields the following:

```
[StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 0), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 1),
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 2), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 3), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 4), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 5), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 6), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 7), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 8), 
StackOverflowPlayground.Age(position: 9)]
```